# Can't find SUMIF in my Numbers functions. Could someone tell me where to find it?

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, numbers

For the first time I am working with Numbers rather than Mac Exel, which I was running on my old G4. I now have a 2012 MacBook Pro with Mavericks, and the one function I use more than any other is SUMIF. However, this does not appear in my menu of choices. Can I add it?

Answer (score 1):

To get to SUMIF you need to call up the function browser. To do that go to the cell where you want the result to appear and hit the '=' key and it will appear as a popup

[image]